# can't access command-line arguments from inside a function

Tags: bash, function

my script does not appear to be working even though I get an exit status of 0

It worked until I made it a function with the

```
makedrivetree ()
{
}
```

syntax.

If remove that and keep everthing between the `while` and `done` it works fine.

I have it saved in my ~/bin folder as makedrivetree

Here is the full function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# a script to write the contents of a directory in tree form and save it to a .txt file

### CONSTANTS

DATE="$(date +%Y%m%d)"

### FUNCTIONS

makedrivetree ()

{
    while [ "${*}" != "" ] ; do

        #set $DRIVE as the first arugment sent to script
        DRIVE="${1}"
        #set $OUTPUT
        OUTPUT="/Users/$USER/Desktop/$(basename "${DRIVE}")_contents_"${DATE}".txt"
        #run tree
        tree -I "*.dpx" --si --du -U -o "${OUTPUT}" "${DRIVE}"

        #check $? for errors
        if [ "$?" -eq "0" ] ; then
            echo 'done. moving to next drive.'
        else
            echo 'error'
        fi

        shift

    done
}

#call the function(s)

makedrivetree

echo 'makedrivetree exited with status' $?

exit
```

Comment: You don't pass parameters to your function, that's probably the problem.

Comment: hi @Aaron can you elaborate or suggest a fix? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see. I have to do something like `makedrivetree $@` when I call the function.

Comment: Yeah that's it!

Comment: FYI -- instead of `tree ...; if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then ...`, consider `if tree ...; then` -- both shorter, and less bug-prone (so something like extra logging can't disrupt `$?`).

Comment: Also, consider using lower-case characters for your own variable names as [advised by POSIX convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) -- all-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the system or shell, whereas names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. (This is explicitly defined for environment variables, but setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so the convention necessarily applies in both cases).

Comment: @fedepad, the example you've given is part of why the ABS is frowned on as a reference -- it has a tendency to showcase bad practices in its examples. The `function` keyword makes your code needlessly nonportable, while adding no benefits over POSIX-standardized declaration syntax (unlike other bashisms which actually add value). Consider the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) or the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) as alternate reference sources without these faults.

Comment: As an aside -- instead of a `while` loop that runs `shift`, consider `for drive; do` -- that'll implicitly iterate over `"$@"`, your function's arguments, assigning each one to `"$drive"` in turn. You could also write it as `for drive in "$@"; do` to be more explicit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy would `for drive; do` work with your earlier FYI suggesting `if tree ...; then` ?

Comment: Sure, there's no conflict between the approaches.

Comment: OK. I'm not quire sure how it all comes together but I'll look into your suggestions! Thank you very much! @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @Bleakley, ...as a quick example: `date=$(date +%Y%m%d); makedrivetree() { local drive; for drive; do output=$HOME/Desktop/${drive##*/}_contents_${date}; if tree -I "*.dpx" --si --du -U -o "$output" "$drive"; then echo "done. moving to next drive" >&2; else echo "error" >&2; fi; done; }`

Comment: @Bleakley, ...`${drive##*/}` expands `$drive` stripping everything from the beginning to the last `/` much more efficiently than `basename`, which requires spawning a subprocess, running an external program, reading that external program's output, etc.; see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy! The way it was the script would write the tree even is `$drive` didn't exist. I tried fixing that with an additional if statement but I broke something - `{
 local drive ;
 if [ -d $drive ] ; then
  for drive ; do
   output=$HOME/Desktop/${drive##*/}_contents_${date}
   if tree --filelimit 30 --si --du -U -Q -o "${output}" "${drive}" ; then
     echo "done. moving to next drive" >&2
   else
     echo "error" >&2
   fi
 else
  echo -e $bired'Error' $drive 'does not exist.'$color_off
 fi
done
}`

Comment: @Bleakley, `[ -d "$drive" ]`; quotes are important. That's not the only bug -- http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: @Bleakley, ...also, what you posted back to me is missing some `;`s, though that may just be an artifact of expanding it out into multiple lines and then pasting it into a comment.

Comment: @Bleakley, ...on a different point, don't use `echo -e`. Any shell which does anything but print `-e` on its output given that argument is breaking the POSIX specification. Bash does that, yes, but not always -- if you have an instance compiled with `--enable-xpg-echo-default`, you might find yourself being surprised.

Comment: ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132856/discussion-between-bleakley-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: @Bleakley, ...another thing -- the `[ -d "$drive" ]` needs to be inside the `for drive`; otherwise, it hasn't yet been assigned yet, so there's no point to testing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any argument to that function. Check out your first line of code in the function

```
while [ "${*}" != "" ]
```

what you did there was testing if any argument was passed to the function. When you called the function ( makederivetree ), you did not pass any argument to it . To summarise everything , when you called your function , while loop never runs , because of the condition you specified.

Comment: Cool. Thanks! @0.sh.

Comment: Is there a preference over passing parameters via `$@` or `$1`?

Comment: Also, why did it still exit with a 0 if the function never really even ran?

Comment: because you did not specify any return code, so since no keyword or builtin command related error occur bash assumes that the function executed properly .

Comment: @Bleakley - the function ran. It just didn't execute the block inside the while loop because it never received any parameter.

Comment: @0.sh - there is no assumption made by bash. Bash executed the function but the condition in the while loop is false so it went to the next line, which is the end of the function.

Comment: @Bleakley, ...the question doesn't really make sense. `"$1"` refers to the first parameter. `"$@"` refers to *all* parameters. If you're passing something as `$1`, then you're also passing it in `"$@"`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you. I'll read more about $1 and $@ as I'm not totally clear what the purpose of each is...

Comment: ...so, let's say that you run `set -- "first arg" "second arg"` (or had your function called with `yourfunc "first arg" "second arg"`. In either case, `"$1"` evaluates to `first arg`, whereas `"$@"` evaluates to two shell words, the first of those words being `first arg`, and the second being `second arg`.

Comment: BTW, `while (( $# ))` would be another way to check the number of arguments remaining, and a little less inefficient than using `"$*"` to consolidate all those arguments into a string.

Answer (score 1):

calling the function with `makedrivetree "$@"` solved the problem.

(Excellent tips/explanations/answers in the comments, as well)

Comment: That's actually buggy. Use `makedrivetree "$@"` instead -- with `$@` unquoted, then `./yourprogram "first argument" "second argument"` gets passed the same way as `./yourprogram "first" "argument" "second" "argument"`.

Comment: Thanks! @CharlesDuffy